# Should I dynamically generate android activities?

Tags: android

I am building my first Android application that will guide the user through a series if listViews containing categories until the user reaches the final activity where a large block of text will be displayed.

My question is:

Can and should I build the listViews dynamically in one activity or should I build them all in eclipse manually?

There will be a lot of activities.  I dont mind building them, i just dont want to bog down the application.  From what I understand Android does a pretty good job  of destroying old activities, but I am not sure the impact of having hundreds of activities would be.

Thanks in advance for your advice.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like one activity containing a ViewFlipper to hold the list(s). Presumably the list isn't the *only* thing you'll be wanting to display. You'll probably want to show a heading of some kind, and the user's location in the hierarchy.

Answer (score 0):

What if the user hits back button? Will the app navigate to the previous activity?? Or will it be disabled?
I would suggest you make different activities since its the easiest way to do

Comment: That was a concern of mine as well.  However it wouldnt be an issue do build a navigation bar.  I would just rather Android handle that.

Comment: In Android, you dont actually need a navigation bar like you have it in iOS. The back button will do most of the part.